# convert TypeScript object to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, object

I want to convert a typescipt object to JSON

```
ObjectToConvert = { key : value }

public getJson(key: string, value: string) {
    //I passed this values when I called the method : key="attr",value="on"
   console.log(JSON.stringify({ ObjectToConvert }))
   // The result is {"key":"on"} instead of {"attr":"on"}
```

I want to know why the result is not what I passed as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names):

```js
ObjectToConvert = { [key] : value }
```

Comment: it works, thank you for helping :)